# Simple probability mass function question

Tags: probability, statistics, random

I was wondering why given the probability of an event $P(X>n)=\frac{1}{(n+1)}$ then $P(X=n)=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$. Could anyone lend me some help please? 
Thank you so much

Comment: Just a thought: $P(X=n)$ is the probability of $X$ taking a particular value which has to be less, thats why we have larger denominator in $P(X=n)$. However when $P(X>n)$ is the probability of an larger set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Since $\{n\} \cup \{n+1,n+2,...\} = \{n,n+1,n+2,...\}$, and these sets are disjoint, we have $P \{n\} + P \{n+1,n+2,...\} = P \{n,n+1,n+2,...\}$.

Details:

> $$P \{n\}  = P \{n,n+1,n+2,...\} - P \{n+1,n+2,...\}= \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}= \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt answer. Hopefully I will get better at this.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably $N$ and $X$ are the same.

Hint: If $X$ takes only integer values, $X = n$ means: $X > n-1$ but not $X > n$.